# web3 python ethereum raw transaction

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

im getting this error while trying to send ethereum using my local geth node.

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}
```

here is how i  build the tx

```
from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

amount = 0.01
from_address = "0xF2........."
private_key = "cf.........."
address_to = "0x..."
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address)

tx = {
  'from': from_address,
  'to': address_to,
  'value': w3.toWei(amount, 'ether'),
  'gas': 21000,
  'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
  'nonce': nonce,
  'chainId': 1
}
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=private_key)
send = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
txid = send.hex()
```

My ethereum account has more than 2 ETH available
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happened here, did you resolve it?

Comment: yes, my geth node was not fully synchronized, thanks for getting bwck to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node error does not lie, so the node does not think you have 2 ETH available.

You can easily check with `web3.eth.getBalance()` how much you have available.